# Join tables without foreign key relation and add a column to the result in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

In a query I am joining many tables and get the result like this:

```
ID   ORDER_NUMBER   PRICE    
===  ============   =====   
01    21            100        
02    22            300        
03    23            400    
04    24            900
05    25            100
```

Now I need to add 1 column (ITEMNAME.NAME) from a different table (table name is ITEMNAME).
Here is the table ITEMNAME:

```
ID   PRICE      NAME 
===  ======  ============
20     100      Tablet    
50     300      PC
64     400      XBox
99     900      Laptop
```

AND from the above data I WANT (my expecting result):

```
ID   ORDER_NUM   PRICE    NAME
==   =========   ======   ============
01      21       100      Tablet
02      22       300      PC 
03      23       400      XBox
04      24       900      Laptop
05      25       100      Tablet
```

Note: The only way we can join ITEMNAME table by its PRICE column.

I mean I want to display the item name next to my current results matching by its price in the ITEMNAME table. Please notice this at ID# 01 and ID# 05 in my expected final result.

Or if you have any other way to achieve it, please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: As soon as one of those items goes on sale, you're in trouble.

Comment: Couldn't you just add another join based on the price column you already have to bring in the itemname table and then add it to the results?

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing a serious application, then you really need to make an adjustment to your table design right away.  The `price` column is not a reliable join column for at least 2 reasons:

- More than one `item` could have the same `price`.
- What happens when you decide to change the price of an `item`?

Instead, consider adding an `item_id` column to your `orders` table that would be a foreign key on `itemname.id`.

Then, your query would only need a simple join on that foreign key relationship to give you back the results reliably:

```
select o.id, o.order_number, o.price, i.name
  from orders o
  join itemname i
    on i.id = o.item_id
 order by o.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Say select ID, Order_Number, Price from Table1 gives

ID   ORDER_NUMBER   PRICE
===  ============   =====
01    21            100
02    22            300
03    23            400
04    24            900
05    25            100

```
select t1.ID, t1.Order_Number, t1.Price,(select ITEMNAME.NAME from ITEMNAME where ITEMNAME.PRICE = t1.Price) from Table1 t1
```

But be aware the above code might give you exact fetch more number of record. For that u need to use distinct or Rownum=1 depends on your requirement.